# Difficulty with formatting a string to parse to date in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
dim dt as string= "03/22/20 20:12:27.320"

Dim tempDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat)
```

This gives error sometimes : System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Why?  It seems to be formatted properly. VB.net 4.6.1 framework

Answer (score 1):

"hh" is 12-hour format. 20 is obviously not a valid hour in 12-hour format. If you want 24-hour format then use "HH".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use CDate() function?

```
dim dt as string= "03/22/20 20:12:27.320"
dim tempDate as Datetime = Cdate(dt)
```

or

```
dim tempDate as Datetime = Cdate("03/22/20 20:12:27.320")
```

Comment: That would only work when the system culture is set to US. Everywhere else places the day before the month and so the use of `CDate` would only work correctly for 12 days of the year. The rest of the time it would either fail or, even worse, succeed but produce the wrong value.